# Inline style background-image does not display local images in Reactjs with a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omfAw.png)**strong text**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omfAw.png)

Can someone tell me what I did wrong with the inline style ? when I set the background-image in css file, it display the picture.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, include your code as text and format it as code, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/1220972.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is image loading. I sorted it out by moving the images folder to public folder and then all the images loaded smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding height and width on your style object

```
const style = {
  backgroundImage: `url(pic_${num}`,
  height: "200px",
  width: "200px"
}
```

since div has no content consider adding width and height. If it doesn't work please edit your question or show us what is passed in the `num` variable or maybe show us whats going on the console.

Comment: I think there is a problem with loading image, not with CSS. Thank you!

Comment: You can view the background image path on the style section on the browser inspector.